# Call a function from AppDelegate and use that function to perform segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm trying to call a function from AppDelegate, and using that function I'm trying to perform segue.

[image: My Storyboard]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

```swift
func doSegue (_ verification : Bool) {
    if verification {
        print ("Segue performed")
        LoginVC ()
        .performSegue (withIdentifier: "tosignup", sender: nil)
    }
    else { print("An error occured while login") }
}
func btnremove () {
    print ("Segue performed 1")
    loginbtn.isHidden = true doSegue (true)
}
```

These are the errors which came beyond execution.

[image: These are the errors which came beyond execution.]

Comment: Please tell me what i need to change in this code to get a successful execution?

Comment: You have several view controllers in your project which one of them is the code you posted in because if you are trying to execute it from one other than the LoginVC it won't find the segue which is the error message you are getting.

Comment: Do you do special things on `prepareForSegue` on loginVC ?

Comment: @EduristicIndian If you `@` the person you reply to, they will get the message in their inbox. Quick tip!

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth i am trying to perform segue from LoginVC itself

Comment: @ArashEtemad please guide me how to use it

Comment: So the 'doSegue' method is inside the LoginVC?  Why do you have the line 'LoginVC()' because that is creating a new instance of a LoginVC?

Comment: @EduristicIndian Also, please clean up some comments you made by deleting them that are not useful. Like the top question, and the ones not `@`ing people - just makes it easier to read. You can always edit the question to add the detail instead of using comments. :)

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth i used loginVC(), so as to call the function in loginVC i.e doSegue, and yes doSegue is inside LoginVC

Comment: That's not what is happening.  LoginVC() creates a new instance of your login view controller it does not access the existing one.  Also the '.performSegue' appears to be on the next line which means it will be calling that on the app delegate itself and that doesn't have the segue so you get the error.  You will need to either call that 'doSegue' within the LoginVC itself or hold a reference to your current login view controller in the app delegate and call it on that.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth please guide me how to hold a refrence in AppDelegate and call doSegue, because i want my app to perform segue beyond logging in from google

Comment: Well there are various ways of doing it that depend on how your project is setup and in fact it might be better to refactor things that it is not needed but I will add an answer showing one simple way of doing it.  Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do anything special in prepareForSegue in LoginVC you can initiate the root view controller in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if (verification) {
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignupformVC")

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

Also you should set identifier for your view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Right based on the comments here is a simple method to put a reference to the existing login view controller into the app delegate so that you can perform a segue on it.

First in the app delegate you are going to need to add a property for the reference to the login view controller like this:

```
public var loginVC: LoginVC?
```

Now in the login view controller you can set this property as follows in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
    // Get the app delegate ensuring it is the right type.
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.loginVC = self
    }
```

Then back in the app delegate you can use that property in the `doSegue` method as follows:

```
func doSegue (_ verification : Bool) {
    // Ensure that the loginVC property has been set and if not we can't perform the segue.
    guard let loginVC = self.loginVC else {
        print ("The login view controller is not presented")

        return
    }

    if verification {
        print ("Segue performed")
        // Use the property to perform the segue.
        loginVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tosignup", sender: nil)
    }
    else { print("An error occured while login") }
}
```

Now this might not be the best approach but without knowing more about the project it is a simple method to get it working.